# jQueryで指定された値を取得し書き換えたい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

HTML

```
<ul id="list">
    <li id="meta">hoge<span id="opt">huga</span></li>
    ...
<ul>
```

というテーブルから"hoge"だけをjQueryを使用し取得した後、値を書き換えたいです。
ご教授願えますでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQueryのAPIだけでテキストノードを書き換えることはできないみたいですが、`contents()`で、テキストノードを含めた子要素を取得し、テキストノードオブジェクトの`nodeValue`プロパティを弄れば、一応できそうです。

```
$('#meta').contents()[0].nodeValue = "ABC";
```

絞り込むならこんな感じで。

```
$('#meta').contents().filter(function (){ return this.nodeType === 3; })[0].nodeValue = 'ABC';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#list #meta")[0].innerHTML="hara"+$("#list #meta #opt")[0].outerHTML
```

"hoge"から"hara"に書き換えなります